# Android : Unable to set marquee

Tags: android, xml, marquee

I am not able to implement a Marquee Text View in android.

Yes, this question is similar to many other questions related to Marquee. I have read most of them. I tried implementing Marquee the way many of the answers are. But still my code doesn't work.

Please help me resolve the issue. I have tried everything. Nothing worked.

Thanks.

**XML code :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/mainBg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/marquee"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="@string/home"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA Code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView marqText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.marquee);
    marqText.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is the issue? "My code doesn't work" is too vague. I think your contents in the text of the TextView need to fill more than the width of the screen - so what's the contents of your "home" string resource?

Comment: shows a textview which does not scroll. a still text view

Comment: It only scrolls if the contents don't fit on the screen - what's are you setting the text to? If it's just "home" try a longer string to test it

Comment: i tried putting a longer string. still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `android:singleLine = "true"` to the TextView to keep the text on only one line.

Comment: doesn't android:lines="1" do the same thing ?

Comment: you would think so. I tried your code in a sample app and it doesn't scroll (just the ...) with the `android:lines = "1"` but it does work with `android:singleLine = "true"`

Comment: i tried using android:singleLine="true". but no luck. problem persists

Comment: Did you remove the android:lines tag at the same time?

Comment: yes, i did. I also tried setting focus to the text view.

Answer (score 2):

If `TextView` fill whole width you need to add these lines of code

```
<TextView
    .
    .
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
```

also do not forget to set selected for `TexrtView` as below

```
textview.setSelected(true);
```

and if `TextView` does not fill width the only thing is to call this method and pass `TextView` to it.

```
    fun addMarquee(textView: TextView) {
    textView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val pixels = textView.measuredWidth - 1
            val params = textView.layoutParams
            params.width = pixels
            textView.layoutParams = params
            textView.isSelected = true
            textView.ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE
            textView.isSingleLine = true
            textView.marqueeRepeatLimit = -1
            textView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })
}
```

**NOTE:** this method only work when textView width is `wrap_content`.